# Nest.js on Cloud Run running scheduled jobs with bull throws random connection errors?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, nestjs, google-cloud-run, bull

I'm trying to perform 3rd party API requests for fetching loads of paginated data (an array of ~16k objects with each object having ~25 key/value pairs), i thought i was getting rate limited but the requests run fine locally and in production as well when triggered manually

but when they run on schedule by bull i get these random connection errors

```
errorMessage: 'Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established',
errorStack: 'Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established\n' +
  '    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)\n' +
  '    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1585:19)\n' +
  '    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)\n' +
  '    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)\n' +
  '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)'
```

```
errorMessage: 'socket hang up',
errorStack: 'Error: socket hang up\n' +
  '    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)\n' +
  '    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:471:23)\n' +
  '    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:402:35)\n' +
  '    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)\n' +
  '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)'
```

```
errorMessage: 'read ECONNRESET',
errorStack: 'Error: read ECONNRESET\n' +
  '    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20)'
```

```
errorMessage: 'write ECONNRESET',
errorStack: 'Error: write ECONNRESET\n' +
  '    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:98:16)'
```

I'm running a Nest.js server on Cloud Run

Here's my Docker configuration

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

# Copy and install dependencies first so that they can be cached
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install

# Copy rest of the files and build
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
RUN ls -a

FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Copy and install dependencies first so that they can be cached
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install --prod

# Copy files and dist folder from build image
COPY . .
COPY --from=build /app/dist ./dist
RUN ls -a


EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "dist/src/main.js"]
```

This instance has 4GiB memory, 2 CPUs, request timeout set to 2400 seconds and maximum requests per container to 80, minimum & maximum number of instances are set to 1 and 25 respectively.

And all of the traffic is routed through a VPC connector, it is a `f1-micro` instance with min instances set to 2 and max 10.

For bull there are 5 different workers setup which are randomly assigned to the job

I wasn't getting these errors on App Engine where this was previously deployed to

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest review the Concurrency value set in Cloud Run.
By default each Cloud Run container can receive 80 requests at the same time but you can increase to a maxim of 1000, you can modify this value depending if your code can process parallel requests at the same time, in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/concurrency) you can find how to set your concurrency value  to Cloud Run